# Assign coordinates to grid-cell in QGIS

Tags: vector-grid

I've created a grid using `make grid` in QGIS. The type of grid is rectangular (polygon) and it's 0,1 x 0,1 decimal degrees. I now want to assign an X and Y coordinate to the centre of each grid. Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the field calculator and add a new field `centroid_x`, type decimal, computed as `x(centroid($geometry))` (the X coordinate, of the centroid of the current (=each) geometry.)

Add a second field  `centroid_Y` computed as `y(centroid($geometry))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked!